# What defines Google Chrome window location?

Tags: google-chrome, gui, window, coordinates

In Google Chrome, when i want to open new window in incognito mode, i press CTRL+Shift+N.

It opens new window in certain location.
My question is: What defines coordinates of that location??

How can i define these coordinates??

i suspect, this question applies to any windows GUI application in general.

Please, help me understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it always opens a few pixels down and to the left of the current Chrome window.

I'm assuming that it's hard coded in the application and that you won't be able to override them.

The same will be true of any other application too. It will either be hardcoded to a specific location (not necessarily absolute values, but centred on the screen etc.), remember the location of the last time it was opened or will be random.